# Could someone with twtelecom inform them that they have a faulty router?

Tags: router, networking

I did a trace route to see where the packets stop when requesting match.com and I noticed that they always stop at the same router using tracert:

Tracing route to us.match.com.akadns.net [208.83.243.15]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
  1     5 ms     3 ms     3 ms  DD-WRT [192.168.2.1] 
  2    12 ms     9 ms    11 ms  10.152.0.1 
  3    12 ms     9 ms    10 ms  172.23.9.221 
  4    19 ms    17 ms    17 ms  172.23.9.1 
  5    25 ms    23 ms    50 ms  xe-10-1-0.bar1.Cleveland1.Level3.net [4.53.196.1] 
  6   136 ms    33 ms    38 ms  ae-6-6.ebr1.Washington1.Level3.net [4.69.136.190] 
  7    33 ms    34 ms    29 ms  ae-71-71.csw2.Washington1.Level3.net [4.69.134.134] 
  8    28 ms    31 ms    41 ms  ae-2-70.edge2.Washington4.Level3.net [4.69.149.80] 
  9    35 ms    32 ms    39 ms  GOOGLE-INC.edge2.Washington4.Level3.net [4.53.114.10] 
 10    70 ms    32 ms   129 ms  ash1-ar2-xe-2-0-0-0.us.twtelecom.net [66.192.251.6] 
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 ...
```

I called twtelecom.net and they told me to use an email address (netabuse@twtelecom.net) to inform them of the problem.  However when I send the email, it also doesn't reach it's destination!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the tracert stops there doesn't mean it's a faulty router.  They could be blocking ICMP traffic by design.  Also, the tracert GETS to the twtelecom.net router.  It dies off at the next hop.

Comment: But wouldn't tw telecom be able to find out what the next hop would have been? The connection is just spotty is all.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.